# Nomenclatural/Semantic Question in re: Semiotics

Tags: terminology, semantics

I just had a quick nomenclatural/semantic question regarding the usage of the term "semiotics". Thought this would be a good place to ask it, so here I am. Anyways, my question has to do with using the term semiotics to refer the **study** of signs/signal processes vs. using the term to refer to a substantive **system** of signs and signal processes. In particular, I wanted to know whether the latter usage is generally considered "acceptable".

For example, consider a system of behavioral heuristics and situationally-dependent/adaptive rules of "right" conduct functioning in some hypothetical modern society. (Here I would point to F.A. Hayek's formulation of "culture" as particularly illustrative instantiation of this concept.) To the extent that such a system is based on:

-abstract signifiers (e.g., social-psychological schemata)

-signs (e.g., normatively salient social cues)

-signal processes (e.g., reciprocal, adaptive cue-based interaction(s))

...could one call this a "semiotics of social morality"? Or is this a grievous abuse of terminology?

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

(**P.S.** -  I am aware that semantics is branch of semiotics, so this whole question is delightfully meta and such. Funny coincidence, but unintentional.)

(**P.P.S.** - Also, I know that my formulation of a system of behavioral heuristics/rules of conduct glosses over the fact that addressing ontological questions as to the *nature* of such a system and epistemological questions as to what can be said to be *known* about such a system necessarily implies (or presupposes) some form of "study". I suppose what I am trying to ask is whether the substantive "output" of such inquiry [i.e., "knowledge" of some extant system of signs and signal processes undergirding certain supervenient phenomena] can itself be called a "semiotics of phenomenon X".)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no** entry in *SEP* about *semiotics*.

We have [Peirce's Theory of Signs](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/) where we read that, according to Peirce :

> "I define a sign as anything which is so determined by something else, called its Object, and so determines an effect upon a person, which effect I call its interpretant, that the later is thereby mediately determined by the former."

So, may be of your interest the link Peirce states between *signs* and *effects* (upon a person), and this is the "pragmatic flavour" of P's thought.

The traditional "organization" of [Semiotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics) divided it :

> into three branches:
>
> *Semantics* : Relation between signs and the things to which they refer; their denotata, or meaning
>
> *Syntactics* : Relations among signs in formal structures
>
> *Pragmatics* : Relation between signs and sign-using agents

You may be interested into the last one, which involves *agents*.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll definitely take some time to look into Peirce and pragmatics in more detail.